# Integrals for children

Tags: integration

I was just reviewing a chapter on integration defined through step functions, and was wondering how would you explain the concept of an integral of a step function to a child ?

Comment: Just sum of area of rectangles. In fact, integral can be viewed as the "limit" of these sort of sums.

Comment: Define "child."

Comment: Child : 10 year old

Comment: Then I would go with what @achillehui said.

Comment: If that child was Gauss, I think there is no such concern. :P And I am curious about the relations between Gauss and "Gauss" functions.

Comment: You won't. A ten year old child will not have a solid notion of a function.  So: cui bono? There gazillion math related topics to keep those children stunning.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I didn't mean defining an actual integral but the idea behind it.

Comment: Don't do it.  A ten year old child isn't interested in such things for a lacking background.  Also regard that a ten year old child is hardly to be supposed to know what a variable is.  Consider also their capability to calculate.  I'ld go for something different.

Comment: Michael, maybe this child is from India or China? My cousin was doing derivatives at age 12. He got done with Bsc in engineering at age 20, whereas I at that age, well never mind...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: I think you severely underestimate the thinking ability of a child...  If the question is whether to present an abstract notion of how to find area of a figure, and an option is presented as taking a sum of decreasing-size increasing count of rectangles, I would say that approach would be well-received by a child interested in the topic.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: as for interest, how many children play games like SimCity or The Sims?  One of the basic properties of such games is that applying something like carpet or industrial zoning to an area comes with a cost proportional to the area, which means that at some point it is helpful to know the area to know how much a thing will cost.  That's just an example I can think of, I'm sure there are others...

Comment: Maybe this gives some intuition:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543176/what-situations-models-require-calculating-the-area-under-a-curve/543269#543269